# Как вывести полученный json постранично?

Tags: ios, swift

Есть приложения для сайта. Проблемы с выводом полученной информации на экран телефона. Сам json я получаю, корректно парсю, вывожу часть данных в tableView. Все полученные данные выводятся.

Как реализовать вывод постранично? Есть ли стандартные средства в xcode, чтобы автоматом разбивать полученный json в приложении?

Если автоматом нельзя, то как можно(подойдут просто ссылочки понятным мануалом). Если на стороне клиента(телефона) нет такой возможности сделать, то буду дописывать api сайта, чтобы он отдавал данные постранично. Но тогда вопрос будет, как их корректно принимать.

Какой из этих способов более правильный? Разделять данные на стороне сервера или на стороне клиента?

Comment: Думаю Вам стоит пересмотреть архитектуру приложения. Более логично будет запрашивать контент постранично. А не получать контент в избытке и потом скролить его.

Comment: не совсем понятно, что вы хотите сделать. получили вы json, сконвертировали допустим в NSArray, вывели на экран в tableView. что такое вывести постранично? допустим на экран вместилось 10 элементов, вам надо чтоб когда пользователь сделает свайп, таблица сдвинулась на 10 и показала следующие 10?

Comment: Хорошо. Допустим сервер мне присылает ответ, что в ответе будет 7 страниц по 15 элементов и возвращает первые 15 элементов. Как в приложении для ios показать пользователю, что тут 7 страниц со списком? С выводом 15 элементов проблем не должно быть

Comment: @Makarenko_I_V, посмотрите комментарий выше

Comment: @max, нет, не совсем. Я хочу, чтобы данные выводились на разных страницах. На первой - 10 штук, например, на второй - 10 штук и так далее, пока все ответы сервера не закончатся. С возможностью навигации по этим страницам(пагинация)

Comment: вопрос больше по дизайну, чем о программированию. чтобы оказать, что у вас там 7 страниц, используйте UIPageControl. Чтобы показать 15 и загрузить и показать больше, при достижении низа списка проще всего найти готовое решение на гитхабе

Comment: @max, а не подскажешь, как закрыть тему?